# Spring 3 RestTemplate to WebClient

Tags: spring, webclient, spring-webflux, resttemplate, spring-reactor

I'm trying to migrate Spring version 3 RestTemplate with the WebClient. But I'm getting this compilation error while doing this migration.

```
cannot access org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference
```

Here is the Spring RestTemplate code that I'm trying to change

```
private ResponseEntity<Assignment[]> getAssignmentsPage(RestTemplate restTemplate, HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity, String url) {

            ResponseEntity<Assignment[]> responseEntity =
                    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Assignment[].class);        

            return responseEntity;
    }
```

Replaced code with WebClient

```
Flux<Assignment[]> quoteFlux = WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri(url)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Assignment[].class);
```

Here are the POM file configurations

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
</properties><dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>                
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- added       -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Flux should be of type

`ParameterizedTypeReference<Assignment[]>(){}`

Please check this out: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20195

Comment: @Adek Fixed the link.

Comment: @ Sashank and @Michael. I have changed the code and added Spring core (5.2.6) dependency for ParameterizedTypeReference. but I'm getting a different runtime error (NoClassDefFoundError) that is from Log4jConfigListner.

Comment: Hi @Adek . I did not know about this. Did some search and found out that the Log4jConfigListener has been removed as of Spring 4.2.1, in favor of Apache Log4j 2. Can you configure this listener class to see if the original issue is fixed?